# Why is CustomPaint's paint() method called on every setState() if it contains a TableRow?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

I have a simple `CustomPainter` in a Flutter app that always returns `false` from its `shouldRepaint()` method and `print()`s when the `paint()` method is called.

While debugging something, I noticed that the `paint()` method was being called much more frequently than I would expect (every second - which is how often `setState` is being called due to an on-screen timer).

I trimmed my code down and found that this stops happening if I remove the `Table`/`TableRow`, the repaints stop. Putting them back causes the frequent repaints again. I see this on both when running on macOS and Web devices.

I'm curious - what is it about `Table`/`TableRow` that causes the `CustomPainter` to be repainted on every `setState`?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Setting this value to 'true' which simply adds a Table/TableRow around
/// the container causes the CustomPaint's `paint` method to be called after
/// every setState(), whereas when set to 'false' (no Table/TableRow), it is not
/// called.
const wrapInTable = true;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          // These don't have any impact
          // willChange: false,
          // isComplex: true,
          foregroundPainter: GridPainter(),
          child: wrapInTable
              ? Table(children: [
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Container(),
                  ])
                ])
              : Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
}

class GridPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print('##### PAINTING!');

    const topLeft = Offset(10, 10);
    const bottomRight = Offset(20, 20);
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromPoints(topLeft, bottomRight),
      Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = 1
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = Colors.red,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant GridPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I'm aware that the Flutter docs say that the `paint()` method may be called more than I expect, including when I return `false` from `shouldRepaint`. I'm specifically trying to understand what's triggering it here, as something to watch out for when trying to minimise repaints.

Comment: You can use [RepaintBoundary](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RepaintBoundary-class.html) to improve it.

Comment: I did try adding one but it didn't seem to help (although I wasn't sure where it'd go). Although my question here is about why the difference when adding the Table rather than how to prevent it.